# Why are new projects in VS2015 targeting .NET 4.5.2 instead of 4.6.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just created a new console project in Visual Studio 2015 and noticed the project is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2 instead of the newer 4.6.1, why is this?

Comment: It is just whatever you used previously.  We don't know why you picked 4.5.2 a week ago.

Comment: @HansPassant, no I just created a new console project today, and didn't get to make any selection, just clicked new project, and it was 4.5.2 instead of latest .NET framework.

Answer (score 3):

The "New Project" screen allows you to pick the target framework. It may not be as obvious:

[image]

If the expected framework is not there, download the targetting pack from the <kbd><More Frameworks...></kbd> link

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. However, why is 4.5.2 the default selected option, instead of 4.6.1?

Comment: I suppose since that's what most people currently have installed. It ships by default on Windows 8.1 and has been force-pushed to Windows 7. The same cannot be said about 4.6 yet.